# Account creation page only accepts password with exactly 8 characters? [trouble when pasting passwords]

Tags: bug, user-accounts, password

I just created an account and had trouble using a randomly generated long password. I got an error mentioning the rules of at least 8 characters and letters and numbers. I reduced the length of the password in some steps (16, 12, 8) … when I reached 8, it got accepted.

This can't be right, right? Is there an actual length limit on passwords?

I am using Firefox 60.2.0 ESR with NoScript, but stackexchange.com is whitelisted, as is ajax.googleapis.com. Here is a screenshot from a test attempt:

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Update: I noticed that the trouble starts when I paste the password using the middle mouse button. There is a timing issue with the code that checks the password as it is typed. It gets confused when pasting in the password … as you do when using a password manager! When I click around for a while after pasting, the error message eventually disappears and I can proceed.

Comment: No repro on Chrome / Win 10.

Comment: You might want to capture network traffic in your browser's dev tools to see how the server actually responded to the change request. If it's a 500 the timestamp on the request will help them track it down. Or the response may simply contain the actual issue.

Comment: Use a different browser all together. Logout is found in the hamburger menu top right.

Comment: Thanks for the hamburger tip. For some reason the logout was not visible to me before there.

Comment: I updated with my recent insights. Pasting seems to be the issue. Me having deleted the last characters manually going from 12 to 8 fixed the check because I was _typing_, not because of the password contents.